# Is there any equivalent of `pwd -L` in perl?

Tags: perl, symlink, pwd

Is there an equivalent of shell's "pwd -L" in perl?

I want the current working directory with symlinks unresolved?

My current working directory is "/path1/dir1/dir2/dir3", and here dir1 is symlink to test1/test2. I want current working directory to be "/path1/dir1/dir2/dir3" via perl script. What I am getting is /path1/test1/test2/dir2/dir3.

How can I get the current working directory to be the path with no symlinks resolved? In other words, I would want to implement shell's `pwd -L`.

Comment: What about `$ENV{PWD}`?

Comment: Have you tried [Cwd](https://perldoc.perl.org/Cwd)?

Answer (score 2):

use the perl backtick operator to run the pwd -L command on your system and capture the output into a variable, this works on my system:

```
 perl -e 'chomp( my $pwdl = `pwd -L` ); print "$pwdl\n";'
```

Comment: The command will return the trailing `"\n"` so you don't need to add one more

Comment: Which is to say, Perl's backticks, unlike the shell's, does not strip trailing newlines.

Comment: Which is to say `$pwdl` didn't actually contain (just) the path, so I fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

An attempt to replicate the behavior of `bash`'s `pwd` builtin using just `perl` (In particular, with the aid of the [`Path::Tiny`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny) and core [`Cwd`](https://perldoc.perl.org/Cwd) modules):

First, from `help pwd` in a `bash` shell:

> - -L        print the value of `$PWD` if it names the current working directory
> - -P        print the physical directory, without any symbolic links

(The GNU coreutils version of `pwd(1)` also reads the PWD environment variable for its implementation of `-L`, which is why running it with `qx//` works even though it doesn't have access to the shell's internal variables keeping track of the working directory and path taken to it)

```sh
$ pwd -P # First, play with absolute path with symlinks resolved
/.../test1/test2/dir2/dir3
$ perl -MCwd -E 'say getcwd'
/.../test1/test2/dir2/dir3
$ perl -MPath::Tiny -E 'say Path::Tiny->cwd'
/.../test1/test2/dir2/dir3
$ pwd -L # Using $PWD to preserve the symlinks
/.../dir1/dir2/dir3
$ /bin/pwd -L
/.../dir1/dir2/dir3
$ PWD=/foo/bar /bin/pwd -L # Try to fake it out
/.../test1/test2/dir2/dir3
$ perl -MPath::Tiny -E 'my $pwd = path($ENV{PWD}); say $pwd if $pwd->realpath eq Path::Tiny->cwd'
/.../dir1/dir2/dir3
```

As a function (With some added checks so it can handle a missing `$PWD` environment var or one that points to a non-existent path):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw/say/;
use Path::Tiny;

sub is_same_file ($$) {
    my $s1 = $_[0]->stat;
    my $s2 = $_[1]->stat;
    return $s1->dev == $s2->dev && $s1->ino == $s2->ino;
}

sub get_working_dir () {
    my $cwd = Path::Tiny->cwd;
    # $ENV{PWD} must exist and be non-empty
    if (exists $ENV{PWD} && $ENV{PWD} ne "") {
        my $pwd = path($ENV{PWD});
        # And must point to a directory that is the same filesystem entity as cwd
        return $pwd->is_dir && is_same_file($pwd, $cwd) ? $pwd : $cwd;
    } else {
        return $cwd;
    }
}

say get_working_dir;
```